# No viable overloaded '=' when using boost odeint with std::map and a custom vector space algebra

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, odeint

I am trying to solve a system of ODEs using std::maps, and utilising boost's odeint. The std::map isn't supported by default so I followed the relevant steps from [the boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/numeric/odeint/doc/html/boost_numeric_odeint/odeint_in_detail/state_types__algebras_and_operations.html) to define a custom vector space algebra.

On compile, I get the following error:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/numeric/odeint.hpp:32:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/numeric/odeint/stepper/runge_kutta_dopri5.hpp:25:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/numeric/odeint/stepper/base/explicit_error_stepper_fsal_base.hpp:31:
/usr/local/include/boost/numeric/odeint/util/copy.hpp:43:12: error: no viable overloaded '='
        to = from;

...

note: candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const DeterministicStateType', but method is not marked const
DeterministicStateType& operator=(const DeterministicStateType& a)
```

I am not a C++ expert, but this seems to imply that the = method needs to be const, which doesn't make sense to me.

MWE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>
#include <boost/operators.hpp>

namespace pl = std::placeholders;

class DeterministicStateType :
    boost::additive1< DeterministicStateType ,
    boost::additive2< DeterministicStateType , double ,
    boost::multiplicative2< DeterministicStateType , double > > >
{
public:
    DeterministicStateType(std::map<std::string, double> map) : mMap(map)
    {}

    DeterministicStateType() {}

    DeterministicStateType(const DeterministicStateType &p)
    {
        DeterministicStateType(p.mMap);
    }

    std::map<std::string, double> mMap;

    DeterministicStateType& operator+=(const DeterministicStateType &p)
    {
        for (std::map<std::string, double>::const_iterator it = p.mMap.begin(); it != p.mMap.end(); it++)
        {
            mMap[it->first] = mMap[it->first] + it->second;
        }

        return *this;
    }

    DeterministicStateType& operator+=(double a)
    {
        for (std::map<std::string, double>::const_iterator it = mMap.begin(); it != mMap.end(); it++)
        {
            mMap[it->first] += a;
        }

        return *this;
    }

    DeterministicStateType& operator*=(const double a)
    {
        for (std::map<std::string, double>::const_iterator it = mMap.begin(); it != mMap.end(); it++)
        {
            mMap[it->first] *= it->second;
        }

        return *this;
    }

    DeterministicStateType& operator=(const DeterministicStateType& a)
    {
        mMap.clear();
        std::map<std::string, double> map2 = a.mMap;
        for (std::map<std::string, double>::iterator it = map2.begin() ; it != map2.end(); it++)
        {
            mMap[it->first] = it->second;
        }

        return *this;
    }        
};

DeterministicStateType operator/( const DeterministicStateType &p1 , const DeterministicStateType &p2 )
{
    std::map<std::string, double> map;
    std::map<std::string, double> p2map = p2.mMap;
    for (std::map<std::string, double>::const_iterator it = p1.mMap.begin() ; it != p1.mMap.end() ; it++)
    {
        map[it->first] = it->second / p2map[it->first];
    }
    return DeterministicStateType(map);
}

DeterministicStateType abs( const DeterministicStateType &p )
{
    std::map<std::string, double> map;
    for (std::map<std::string, double>::const_iterator it = p.mMap.begin() ; it != p.mMap.end() ; it++)
    {
        map[it->first] = std::abs(it->second);
    }
    return DeterministicStateType(map);
}

namespace boost { namespace numeric { namespace odeint {
    template<>
    struct vector_space_norm_inf< DeterministicStateType >
    {
        typedef double result_type;
        double operator()( const DeterministicStateType &p ) const
        {
            using std::abs;
            double max = 0;
            for (std::map<std::string, double>::const_iterator it = p.mMap.begin(); it != p.mMap.end(); it++)
            {
                if (abs(it->second) > max)
                {
                    max = abs(it->second);
                }
            }
            return max;
        }
    };
}}}

namespace boost { namespace numeric { namespace odeint {

    template< >
    struct is_resizeable<DeterministicStateType>
    {
        typedef boost::true_type type;
        const static bool value = type::value;
    };

    template< >
    struct same_size_impl<DeterministicStateType, DeterministicStateType>
    {
        static bool same_size(const DeterministicStateType &v1, const DeterministicStateType &v2)
        {
            return v1.mMap.size() == v2.mMap.size();
        }
    };

    template< >
    struct resize_impl<DeterministicStateType, DeterministicStateType>
    {
        static void resize(DeterministicStateType &v1, const DeterministicStateType &v2)
        {
            for (std::map<std::string, double>::const_iterator it = v2.mMap.begin() ; it != v2.mMap.end() ; it++)
            {
                if (v1.mMap.count(it->first) == 0)
                {
                    v1.mMap[it->first] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    };
}}}

void derivative(const DeterministicStateType p, DeterministicStateType &dpdt, const double t) {}

using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::map<std::string, double> x0; x0["A"]=1.0; x0["B"]=1.0;
    typedef runge_kutta_dopri5<DeterministicStateType, double, DeterministicStateType, double, vector_space_algebra> stepper_type;
    integrate_adaptive( make_dense_output(1e-6, 1e-6, stepper_type()) ,
        derivative, DeterministicStateType(x0), 0.0, 300.0, 0.00001);
}
```

Comment: So, this may not be helpful, but the problem is that your first (and only) argument is being treated as a `this` pointer...in other words, the object you are wanting to modifying with the assignment.  Definitely some boost weirdness going on.  It's similar to how it would treat it if defined outside the class.

Comment: You could try declaring it like `DST& operator=(DST &target, const DST&source)` both inside and outside the class--as separate tests.  Not normally valid syntax, but boost can do some very strange things, and that seems to be what it's expecting.

Comment: @zzxyz Thanks, I tried adding this inside and outside the class. Inside gives `operator= must be a binary operator`. Outside gives `operator= must be a non-static member function` so sadly no fix there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You copy assignment operator takes the rhs as non-const</strike>

```
DeterministicStateType &operator=(DeterministicStateType &a) {
```

This is both not necessary and doesn't compile when the source is const in the calling code. Simply fix it by adding const:

```
DeterministicStateType &operator=(DeterministicStateType const& a) {
```

Even better, simplify all these functions (I think the multiplication was wrong altogether, it didn't even use its argument):

```
State &operator=(State const&a) {
    mMap = a.mMap;
    return *this;
}
```

Even better, assuming you have enabled C++11 on your compiler:

```
State &operator=(State const&a) = default;
```

### Wait why is my error message still here?

That's because now you still pass a temporary to `integrate_adaptive`. Temporaries bind only to `const&`, never to `&`². So, just create your `DeterministicStateType` before the call, and pass it by reference, instead of the temporary `DeterministicStateType(x0)`:

```
int main() {
    DeterministicStateType x0 { { {"A", 1.0}, {"B", 1.0} } };
    typedef runge_kutta_dopri5<DeterministicStateType, double, DeterministicStateType, double, vector_space_algebra>
        stepper_type;
    integrate_adaptive(make_dense_output(1e-6, 1e-6, stepper_type()), derivative, x0, 0.0,
                       300.0, 0.00001);
}
```

### Simplified Code

In this simplified version I used a namespace, made `mMap` private and used C++11 features to make everything a lot less error-prone:

**<kbd>[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Xd7tgpb1DGzveXb4)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>
#include <boost/operators.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

namespace Deterministic {

    class State : boost::additive1<State,
                      boost::additive2<State, double, 
                          boost::multiplicative2<State, double> > >
    {
      public:
        using Map = std::map<std::string, double>;
        State(Map const& map) : mMap(map) {}
        State() = default;
        State(const State &p) = default;
        State &operator=(State const&a) = default;

        State &operator+=(const State &p) {
            for (auto& p : p.mMap) mMap[p.first] += p.second;
            return *this;
        }

        State &operator+=(double a) {
            for (auto& p : mMap)
                p.second += a;
            return *this;
        }

        State &operator*=(double f) {
            for (auto& p : mMap) mMap[p.first] *= f;
            return *this;
        }

        friend State abs(const State &p) {
            using std::abs;
            auto map = p.mMap;

            for(auto& e : map)
                e.second = abs(e.second);

            return map;
        }

        friend State operator/(const State &p1, const State &p2) {
            auto map = p1.mMap;

            for(auto& e : map)
                e.second /= p2.mMap.at(e.first);

            return map;
        }

        friend double vector_space_norm_inf_impl(State const& p) {
            double max = 0;
            using std::abs;
            for (auto& el : p.mMap)
                max = std::max(abs(el.second), max);
            return max;
        }

        size_t size() const { return mMap.size(); }

        void resize(State const& other) {
            for (auto& el : other.mMap)
                mMap[el.first] += 0; // inserts if non-existent
        }

      private:
        Map mMap;
    };
}

using DeterministicStateType = Deterministic::State;

namespace boost { namespace numeric { namespace odeint {
    template <> struct vector_space_norm_inf<DeterministicStateType> {
        typedef double result_type;
        double operator()(const DeterministicStateType &p) const { return vector_space_norm_inf_impl(p); }
    };

    template <> struct is_resizeable<DeterministicStateType> {
        typedef boost::true_type type;
        const static bool value = type::value;
    };

    template <> struct same_size_impl<DeterministicStateType, DeterministicStateType> {
        static bool same_size(const DeterministicStateType &v1, const DeterministicStateType &v2) {
            return v1.size() == v2.size();
        }
    };

    template <> struct resize_impl<DeterministicStateType, DeterministicStateType> {
        static void resize(DeterministicStateType &v1, const DeterministicStateType &v2) {
            v1.resize(v2);
        }
    };
} } }

void derivative(const DeterministicStateType, DeterministicStateType &, const double) {}

using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;

int main() {
    DeterministicStateType x0 { { {"A", 1.0}, {"B", 1.0} } };
    typedef runge_kutta_dopri5<DeterministicStateType, double, DeterministicStateType, double, vector_space_algebra>
        stepper_type;
    integrate_adaptive(make_dense_output(1e-6, 1e-6, stepper_type()), derivative, x0, 0.0,
                       300.0, 0.00001);
}
```

---

² except on broken compilers

Comment: isn't his rhs const?  Your very first code block seems to be his code, but I'm not seeing the `const` declaration which he *does* have.  Or I'm missing something?  I think your 2nd point about temps is his problem, though.

Comment: @zzxyz You're right. While review/cleaning up the code I have been removing `const_iterator` in the first steps. I must have done `n5x` in Vim once too many :) Indeed the temporary was causing the rest of the issue then (isn't it ironic that I discovered that only _after_ "fixing" my own mistake). And then there's the small slew of other issues fixed (notably in `operator*` which worked more like a very clumsily expressed `self_square` :))

Comment: Thanks. I had noticed the broken `operator*` with fresh eyes this morning. The temp didn't occur to me though!

Comment: And you can trim 30% of the code making it more readable :) Cheers